# How AWS ECS works with multiple availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-programming, load-balancing

I have an application build on AWS as structure like this:

- Network: 1 VPC, 2 subnets (A - 10.0.1.0/24 and B - 10.0.2.0/24) belong to 2 differences Availability Zones
- ECS cluster: Available both of subnets, have only 1 ec2 agent which belong to subnet B (I think that because the ip of ec2 agent is 10.0.2.10)
- The cluster have 1 service, which have a network load balancer with DNS name: xxxxx.com

When I try to access to service via DNS name, some request successful, but some request failed (connection timeout)

Then i try to resolve ip addresses from DNS name, i got 2 ips (10.0.1.20 and 10.0.2.30), 1 belong to subnet A, 1 belong to subnet B

Then i send http request to service via ip directly, all requests sent to ip 10.0.2.30 work and all request sent to 10.0.1.20 failed

The problem is, the above behavior happens sometimes, it means not all-time using DNS name failed

I try to draff like below pic, hope it true

[image]

So, i don't understand:

- How ECS multiple Availability Zones works?
- What would happen if i had only 1 task (EC2) run for a service, do multiple availability zones work?
- How many IPs will AWS attack to 1 Network load balancer? depend on subnets or what?
- Can multiple Availability Zones work when only have 1 EC2 Agent belong to 1 subnet(AZ)?

Answer (score 1):

By default Load Balancer endpoints only route traffic to endpoints in their availability zone.

If you have only one Host that runs containers, i.e. all containers/tasks are in a single AZ, then only the Load Balancer endpoint in that AZ can forward traffic to the container.

For both Load Balancer endpoints to work, you must enable [Cross-Zone-Load-Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancers.html#cross-zone-load-balancing). This will enable the Load Balancer in the AZ that doesn't have a backend node to talk to the backend node in the other AZ. Be aware that this incurs data transfer charges, though.

---

> How ECS multiple Availability Zones works?

In a nutshell, it's only Multi-AZ if there are cluster nodes in multiple AZs and more than one task as it will try to spread those out across AZs.

> What would happen if i had only 1 task (EC2) run for a service, do multiple availability zones work?

See above.

> How many IPs will AWS attack to 1 Network load balancer? depend on subnets or what?

One per subnet.

> Can multiple Availability Zones work when only have 1 EC2 Agent belong to 1 subnet(AZ)?

As explained above, with Cross-Zone-Load-Balancing, it can be made to work, but you won't gain much in terms of high availability because your container host remains your single point of failure.